# Conversion doesn't work when I explicitly write it

Tags: c++, casting, c++17

I have 2 classes, each can be converted into other. When I just write for example `a = b` it compiles and converts as expected but when I do for example `a = (OtherClass)b` it  throws me C2440 compile error. Anyone has idea why this happens?

This is what C2440 error says: "retyping: can't convert from Kelvin to Celsius"(and then "from Celsius to Kelvin")

```
#define ValueOperator(VALUETYPE) operator VALUETYPE() const { return this->value; }

using Value = double;

//this is in separated file
class Celsius;
class Kelvin
{
public:
    Value value;
    ValueOperator(Value);

    Kelvin();
    Kelvin(Value value);

    operator Celsius() const;
};

//this is in separated file
class Kelvin;
class Celsius
{
public:
    Value value;
    ValueOperator(Value);

    Celsius();
    Celsius(Value value);

    operator Kelvin() const;
};

int main()
{
    Celsius c = 50;
    Kelvin k = 10;

    c = k; //converts value as excepted
    c = (Celsius)k; //error C2440

    k = c; //converts value as excepted
    k = (Kelvin)c; //error C2440

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't accidentily swapped the types there? `k` is already a `Kelvin` instance, but when you want to convert it into `Celsius`, it should be `(Celsius) k`, no?

Comment: What is C2440? Please add the error message to the question. So far I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?view=msvc-160, one source is "C2440 can also be caused if you attempt to cast from a type that is only forward declared but not defined.". Maybe work with that, should the thing @lubgr talked about not being the source of your error.

Comment: @lubgr yes, I'm sorry i've made mistake in code i pasted here to stackoverflow.

Comment: @churill i've added error message to it now

Comment: Thanks. I still can't reproduce the error. Neither with g++ nor msvc. Maybe there is something wrong with your includes?

Comment: Please make sure that the example code in your question actually reproduces the error.